# Policy to validate API Subscription Key received in Request Body from Google Ads Lead Form Extension using Webhook integration

Tags: azure-api-management

Azure API Management checks for Subscription Key in either the Header or Query, but Google Ads Lead Form extension sends the key in the request body `google_key`

Sample body:

```
    {
  "lead_id": "TeSter-123-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-0123456789-AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLl",
  "api_version": "1.0",
  "form_id": 2,
  "campaign_id": 281492028602095,
  "google_key": "HERE IS THE KEY",
  "is_test": true,
  "gcl_id": "TeSter-123-ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-0123456789-AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLl",
  "adgroup_id": 20000000000,
  "creative_id": 30000000000
}
```

How can we configure a custom policy in Azure API Management to validate the key in the request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built-in architecture in Azure API Management to validate subscription keys that cannot be accessed outside of the built-in Subscription validation.

To use validate the subscription, I created two APIs in Azure API Management. 1 has no security, 2 is secured by Subscription Key and is rate limited.

1. Restructure the request by Appending the Key to the Request Header and removing it from the Request Body

   ```
   <inbound>
   <base />
   <set-header name="google_key" exists-action="append">
       <value>@{
               var reqBody = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true);
               if(reqBody.ContainsKey("google_key"))
               {
                   return reqBody.GetValue("google_key").ToString();
               }
               else
               {
                   return "";
               }
           }</value>
   </set-header>
   <set-body template="none">@{
               var reqBody = context.Request.Body.As<JObject>(preserveContent: true);

               if(reqBody.ContainsKey("google_key"))
               {
                   reqBody.Remove("google_key");
               }
               return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(reqBody);
   }</set-body>
   ```
2. Send the restructured request to the secured API which validates the subscription key.
   [image: Screenshot of Azure API Management Backend definition]